# Python chart click through and filter data table

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I'm looking to use a click through on a bar chart to filter a data table, I can't find anything online that references this question.

If I had a bar chart that referenced parts of a car, one of the bars would be wheels, I click wheels and it filters a data table below to only show the data about wheels. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: There are probably a lot of options. Do you want this in a standard matplotlib GUI or in a notebook in the browser, or in a custom browser application or a custom GUI application? The more details you provide and the more you show of what you have searched for which doesn't help here, the more on-topic the question becomes.

Comment: A standard matplotlib GUI to start so I can get an understanding of what I'm looking at, I would then look to implement this in a custom browser application.

Comment: So if you want to work within a standard matplotlib figure, matplotlib provides [`table`s](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/table_demo.html). You would then connect a [picker](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) to a function that updates the table.